# order relations & doubts

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

It is given a relation $R=\left \{(1,1); (2,2); (3,3); (4,4); (5,5); (3,5); (4,3); (4,2); (4,5); (2,5)\right \}$ for a set $A=\left \{ 1,2,3,4,5\right \}$.

I found this relation is reflexive, anti-symetric and transitive, i.e. an order realation.

If order relation exists, there must be unique factor that is valuable for all ordered pairs in relation, so for all $x$ & $y$ in pairs stands that only $x \gt y$ or $x \lt y$ or $x \ge y$ or $x \le y$.

My questions is: Where I can find here unique order, when $x>y$ in ordered pairs $(4,3)$ & $(4,2)$ or when $x \lt y$ as in ordered pairs $(3,5)$, $(4,5)$ & $(2,5)$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: It is not quite clear what your question really is. The order *is* unique, because you defined $R$ this way. And as you have proved, $R$ is anti-symmetric; so there is no pair for which $x < y$ and $x > y$ holds simultaneously.

Comment: I mean, if this is order relation there must be only one, in this case, inequality sign. R = {(1<=1); (2<=2); (3<=3); (4<=4); (5<=5); (3<=5); (4>=3); (4>=2); (4<=5); (2<=5)} .  If here (4>=3); (4>=2) instead of >= is <= , the order will have unique factor that is valuable for all ordered pairs in relation.

Comment: any idea is welcome

Comment: I think, the problem is that you mix up *your* relation, $R$, with the common *inequality* relation, $\leq$, on the natural numbers. This seems to be the case in the comment, where you suddenly switch from $\leq$ to $\geq$. You better use, as is usually done, the symbol $R$ of your relation. So, instead of $x \leq y$ write $xRy$ when $(x,y) \in R$, and I guess your doubts will disappear.